# How to calculate $\langle x^{(i)},x\rangle$?

Tags: vectors, machine-learning

I am coding [simplified version of Platt's SMO](http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials/smo.pdf) and it defines a function like this:

$$
\newcommand{\<}{\langle}
\newcommand{\>}{\rangle}
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \alpha_iy^{(i)} \<x^{(i)},x\> + \hspace{0.20cm} b
$$

where $x$ is a matrix of dimension $m \times n$
$\alpha$ and $y$ are column vectors of size $m$

I am trying to understand how to calculate $\<x^{(i)},x\>$ since it's apparent that the result of $f(x)$ has to be a scalar.

Comment: Use `\langle, \rangle`.

Comment: What are the training points? What is the dimension of your feature space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the paper says about $\<A,B\>$ is that it's an "inner product".  There are many choices of inner products over matrices (with a corresponding choice of kernel), but the most commonly used inner product in this context is the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product, given by
$$
\<A,B\> = \operatorname{trace}(A^TB) = \sum_{i = 1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}
$$
That is to say, we can simply take the "dot product" of matrices, as one would with vectors.

Comment: Okay so if I were writing this as code, I'd take the i'th row which would be $x^{(i)}$ and then I would dot this with all the rows in the matrix. As I dot $x^{(i)}$ with each row of the matrix, I'd keep getting scalars. I'll add these scalars together and that'd be my answer. Right? N.B: I am not referring to the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product :)

Comment: In the paper, it looks like $x$ and $x^{(i)}$ are matrices of the same size

Comment: No, $x^{(i)}$ is the i'th row of matrix $x$ :)

Comment: Well, that completely throws off my interpretation.  With an inner product (as that term is typically used), the things that go in are two objects of the same type, and its output is a scalar.  If $x$ and $x^{(i)}$ aren't matrices of the same size, I have no idea what he means by an "inner product".  You should probably verify what $x^{(i)}$ is supposed to be.

Comment: In fact: upon a second reading, it looks to me like $x$ and $x^{(i)}$ are both supposed to be column-vectors.  So, the inner product can simply be the usual dot-product.

Comment: Okay, I was digging around for some code and I found this "this is actually the same as multiplying (elementwise) each row of $x$ with its i:th row.", Again, how can this be a scalar ?

Comment: Okay, now I see.  You're using $x$ as your internal variable to keep track of all the columns $x^{(1)},x^{(2)},\dots$ from the iteration.  However, when the author writes $f(x)$, $x$ is just a place-holder for any column-vector.  I'd imagine that, when writing the code, someone found a shortcut in applying $f$ to every column of your matrix $x$.

Comment: Yup, x is a rectangular matrix of size m x n. There's m rows in the dataset, each containing a feature vector with n features. :)

Comment: @LittleChild okay, now read the rest of my comment.  That's what *you* mean by $x$, but that's not what the author means in the context of the function definition.